# Converting images into video using FFMPEG using a Batch script

Tags: ffmpeg, script, video-conversion

I'm using ffmpeg to convert a list of image into a video, I write a batch script to to the job, but it didn't works

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -start_number n -i "IMG0%%.jpg" video.mpg 
-vcodec mpeg4 test.avi
```

Could anyone help please ?
Thank you

Comment: Instead of saying it "didn't work" you should always provide the actual errors.

Comment: Is "n" a placeholder for a number that you need to specify but didn't?

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i img%03d.jpg video.mpg
```

Will read files img001.jpg, img002.jpg, img003.jpg, etc, and output them to a mpg video file, at 24 frames per second.

Of course you can change that to mp4 by just changing the output extension.'

For more info search for [slideshow](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow)